# How to make Wrapper use percent

Tags: css, static, width, wrapper

I'd like to know how to make my wrapper use percentage and grow/shrink with the width of the page instead of staying in one fixed size? I do not want the page to be cut off when I zoom in, would anyone help me with this please, thanks :)

here is a link to the entire phpbb stylesheet

https://gist.github.com/25c59943b244a3e150e8/75c6dd240980864d4872eb6cacccdf980fa9d84c

```
/* Main blocks
---------------------------------------- */
#wrap {
    background-color: #080808;
    padding: 0 0px;
    min-width: 650px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid #161616;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#middle {
    padding: 0 0px;
    min-width: 650px;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#header_1 {
    background-image: url("http://i57.tinypic.com/m81pc0.jpg");
    height: 170px;
    width: 960px;
}

#menus {
    height: 40px;
    border-top: 1px solid #161616;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #161616;
    background: url() repeat-x;
}


#simple-wrap {
    padding: 6px 10px;
}

#page-body {
    margin: 4px 0;
    clear: both;
}

#page-footer {
    clear: both;
}

#page-footer h3 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px 13px 0 10px;
}

a#logo:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: paste your html or fiddle it.

Comment: it's a phpBB3 Style Sheet. I'm not sure what you are asking, specifically for?

Comment: I don't know, but I can't make out its phpBB3 stylesheet. You have not mentioned it in question. Infact I am unaware of phpBB3. So for users like me you can also provide your full code so that I can help you...:)

Comment: i'll try to find somewhere to host the entire code, as this site only allows 30,000

Comment: https://gist.github.com/25c59943b244a3e150e8/75c6dd240980864d4872eb6cacccdf980fa9d84c

Comment: there you go, for anyone looking at the question I have provided the entire phpbb stylesheet on git-hub-gist, hosting site.